# Get value selected from drop down list in where clause using php code

Tags: php

My code is like this:

```
$zone = $_POST['zone'];
$state = $_POST['state'];

$sql = "Select zone_id from tbl_zone where zone_name = $zone";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
```

I am selecting zone name which is fetched from database and listed in drop down list.
Now i want to get id of zone name to store in other table.

In where clause zone_name is blank.
What changes should be done in above code?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What is in $zone? Is it empty?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..

```
$sql = "Select zone_id from tbl_zone where zone_name = '$zone'";
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to design a proper database. Like your question is somewhat confusing. Let me tell you the process. First design 2 tables with 2 columns each. Let us assume table 1 as state and table 2 as city. state table contains 2 columns namely zone_id and zone_state. city table contains 2 columns namely zone_id and zone_city. make state table with zone_id as primary key with auto_increment field and give each id with unique state like zone_id 1 as AP, zone_id 2 as Tamilnadu, zone_id 3 as Karnataka, zone_id 4 as Kerala, zone_id 5 as Maharashtra etc...now for the city table add zone_id with repeated values like zone_id 1 as Hyderabad,zone_id 1 as Vijayawada,zone_id 1 as Vizag, etc..zone_id 2 as Chennai,zone_id 2 as Coimbatore, etc...i hope you got my point...If you design like this then retrieval of results will be easy for you.

see this code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `state` (
  `zone_id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `zone_state` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`zone_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `city` (
  `zone_id` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `zone_city` varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```